# Trouble connecting domain name to Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, web-deployment, cname

I have bought a domain name with Porkbun.com, I have added that domain to my herokuapp domains and received a DNS target. I have added an ALIAS record with host: 'mywebsite.domain' and target as the DNS target I received from Heroku.

When trying to access the domain I get 'bad Request (400)' error. I have then tried these three separate steps:

- As instructed by Porkbun I added another ALIAS record with host: www.mywebsite.domain and target: 'mywebsite.domain'.
- I deleted all the ALIAS records I had and added a CNAME record with host: 'www.mywebsite.domain' and target: 'mywebsite.herokuapp.com'.
- Changed CNAME target to be the DNS record I received from Heroku.

In the three cases I receive a Heroku page saying 'There is nothing here' and titled 'no such app'.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @ArturDumchev Unfortunately, No.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem occurred to me yesterday when i tried to deploy a ghost app to heroku pointing to a custom domain name purchased through porkbun. After googling i found out that the **IT TAKES ALMOST A DAY TO RESOLVE THE DNS POINTING TO THE CUSTOM DOMAIN** in porkbun.

**Solution**

**I changed the CNAME RECORD pointing to the herokuapp url;-"yourappname.heruko.com"**

Add the host as **WWW**

You can also use ALIAS-CNAME RECORDING to point to the heroku app url.

Comment: Also i have tried adding heruko dns to the cname record it also works.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
  heroku domains:add example.com

heroku domains:add www.example.com

heroku domains:add *.example.com
```

This is to point your domain name from heroku side

Check out this video its about connecting your domain name to godaddy. I think its the same way with porkbun youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=75s

Please let me know if this does work for you

Comment: I did these steps on Heroku and added a CNAME on Porkbun similar to the video, but unfortunately the problem remains.
It's worth mentioning that the DNS target I receive on heroku is something like `special-code.herokudns.com` opposed to the typical `example.com.herokudns.com`.